# React Navigation - Tab Navigation - Getting different screens from only one class

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

It is possible to change between tabs without having more then one class?

On my code I have a class that returns multiple components, and I want my TabNavigator to switch between these componentes, not between classes like they have in the React Navigation docs (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation.html).

```
class Monument extends Component{
    render(){
        const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
        const { data } = this.props.navigation.state.params;

        return (
            <MonumentMaker category={'Castelos'} navigate={navigate} data={data}/>
            <MonumentMaker category={'Museus'} navigate={navigate} data={data}/>
            <MonumentMaker category={'Igrejas'} navigate={navigate} data={data}/>
            <MonumentMaker category={'Locais de Interesse'} navigate={navigate} data={data}/>
        );
    }
}

export default TabNavigator({
  Convento: {
    screen:**first component**
  },
  Museus: {
    screen:**second component**
  },
  Igrejas: {
    screen:**third component**
  },
  OutrosLocais: {
    screen:**forth component**
  }
})
```

It is possible what I want to accomplish?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `TabNavigation` as follows

```
const myTabNavigator = TabNavigator({
   Convento: {
    screen: { screen: props => <Monument {...props} {...myProps} /> }
  },
  Museus: {
    screen: { screen: props => <Monument {...props} {...myProps} /> }
  },
  Igrejas: {
    screen: { screen: props => <Monument {...props} {...myProps} /> }
  },
  OutrosLocais: {
    screen: { screen: props => <Monument {...props} {...myProps} /> }
  }
})
```

**Monument.js**

```
const Monument = ({...props}, {...myProps}) => (
  <View>
     {...// More stuff}
  </View>
)
```

Comment: Hi @Pritish, thank you for your answer. But I didn't quit get it what you did there, could you explain me better please? Thks :)

Comment: The Component must remain a `singleTon`, like the `Monument` in your case,  only the `props` must be changed and passed to it, since you're returning the different types of `MonumentMaker class`(which is same just different props are bound to it), therefore you should link it directly link it in the `navigation` and pass `props` according to your convenience.

Comment: Humm ok! Thank you for the help :)
Best regards